# How can I escape "/" character in asciidoc inline anchors?

Tags: asciidoc

I am trying to convert my website documents to asciidoc.But I have problem with asciidoc anchors.When I add / character into the anchor my anchors break down.

The following asciidoc code works:

```
[[en-USdocs...]]
*Tutorials:*
------------
```

The following asciidoc code does not work due to the / character.

```
[[en-US/docs...]]
*Tutorials:*
------------
```

Is there a way to escape that "/" character to allow anchor work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect having a `/` char in an anchor name is invalid HTML, but I think you can make this work with alternate markup.

Try `[id="en-US/docs"]` instead.

My AsciiDoc Preview plugin for Atom balks at it (`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #en-US/docs`)... but it does seem to actually work. I have low confidence all browsers will respect it, however, though I realize you're just trying to reproduce existing functionality, and I think that should give you the same effect.